# Update query in MySQL/VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

**EDIT**
(I'm sorry i have misinformed you guys, this is the true problem)
im only using two textboxes btw.

Is there a way to update a record in mysql without using an **ID**? I mean like,

```
UPDATE table SET name = name1, sex = male1 WHERE name=name1
```

I'm practicing this one on **VB.NET**, just a newbie in this, please can anyone help me? thanks!

Comment: Did you try it? Just remember, that it will replace all records with that name, so if their are different people with the same name, but different first_name it will replace all of them.

Comment: Name is a reserved word in MySql, so you will need to escape it.  That where clause makes little sense.  The name wont be `name1` until after the query runs

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can try with

```
sql = "UPDATE table SET name = name1, sex = male1 WHERE name=@name1"

Try
  With com
    .Connection = con
    .CommandText = sql
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@name1", your_var_name)
 End With
 com.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: what do you mean by "your_var_name"? because when i put Name there nothing changes in my database.

Comment: For your_var_name is mean the var name where you have placed the value that macth with the db fields value (could be name1?) ..